# iphone app checking internet access

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Check for an active Internet Connection on iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)

How can I make my app check for internet access. If it's not available it should present a dialog box telling the user and show the select a network view.

Comment: I also want it to show the select a network view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has [some sample code](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) over at the iOS Dev Center for checking connection status.

Also, you can't invoke the select a network view yourself, it's up to the OS.